# iOS notification override Silent mode - iPhone Alarm Clock App

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, alarm

I am working on an alarm clock App

The alert + music channels through the notification centre

It will not activate if the iPhone is set to silent mode

Many users have requested that the alarm overrides silent mode

Is this possible?

Cheers!

```
(void)addLocalNotification:(myAlarmData *)ma WeekDay:(int)mweekday
{
    UILocalNotification *noti = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSDateComponents *dcom = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];

    [dcom setWeekday:mweekday];
    [dcom setHour:ma.mHour];
    [dcom setMinute:ma.mMinute];
    [dcom setSecond:0];


    NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dcom];

    noti.fireDate = fireDate;
    noti.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    noti.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wake up %@!", [GlobalData gSettings].name];
    noti.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.caf", ma.soundName];
    noti.alertAction = @"OK";

    noti.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

    noti.userInfo = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      ma.mid, @"mid",
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mweekday], @"day",
                      ma.soundName, @"sound",
                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ma.snooze], @"snooze",
                      ma.title, @"title",
                      @"Close", @"action",
                      @"real", @"more",
                      nil] autorelease];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:noti];

    [noti release];
    [gregorian release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can override silent switch to play sounds.

In this case it depends on how iOS manages to play sounds when a notification is triggered.

Have you checked this on device.?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [AudioSession categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html).

AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback should do the trick.